# How to select an item in a listview when using checkboxes in c#?

Tags: listview, select, checkbox, controls, row

I am currently using a listview control in my project with checkboxes. What I cant find out is this: When the user checks a checkbox of an item then the full row of this item is selected, as well, without affecting the other items. I have tried this code:

```
    private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem lvi in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (lvi.Checked)
            {
                lvi.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lvi.Selected = false;
            }
        }
```

but I have some problems when the user unchecks a checkbox. Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I ran into myself and is simply a result of using the ListView *ItemChecked* event instead of *ItemCheck*. From the MSDN sites for [ItemCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemcheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ItemChecked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemchecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
ItemCheck: Occurs when the check state of an item changes.

ItemChecked: This event is similar to the ItemCheck event, but 
             is raised after the item has been checked.
```

You may want to consider the design of your program though, as this is a bit of unnecessary computation. What reason do you have for wanting the ListViewItem.Selected property to mirror that of ListViewItem.Checked? Have you tried simply binding the Selected property to the IsChecked property?